# Dataset from Nasa website

Tags: data-request

I am currently working on my graduation project (" failure prediction models in FoF") and I will be using RapidMiner as the tool, I need dataset to run the tool on , and I found a suitable description in the Nasa website https://data.nasa.gov/external-dataset?datasetId=dc5d-zf5v However I do not know how to access the data itself in form of CSV file in order to start working on it, I have been recommended to using API but I do not know how it exactly work

Comment: You're right - that data catalog entry doesn't seem to have any data related to it and a few searches elsewhere on NASA.gov and the internet didnt turn much up either. Have you reached out to the email on the site which is nasa-data@lists.arc.nasa.gov ?

Comment: "This is a historic Project that was completed before the creation of TechPort on October 1, 2012. Available data has been included. This record may contain less data than currently active projects." from this link http://techport.nasa.gov/view/9418#